# Trying to decode jwt token from server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I have created a CLI with which I consume a data from a rest api I build with node.js and express.js. In the cli the user has to login and after that when he performs a query his data are passed as a header using jwt. This I have done with the following code:

The Login.ts file has this part of the code for the header creation:

```
await connection.query(`SELECT user,pass,email,quota,apikey,privileges FROM users WHERE user=?`,[`${flags.user}`], function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //console.log(`${flags.user}`);
                //console.log(result[0].pass);
                var u=result[0].user;
                var p=result[0].pass;
                var e=result[0].email;
                var q=result[0].quota;
                var a=result[0].apikey;
                var p=result[0].privileges;
                const password=result[0].pass;
                if(bcrypt.compareSync(`${flags.passw}`, password)) {
                    var fs=require('fs');
                    var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
                    var jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
                    var token = jwt.sign({user:`${flags.user}`,passw:`${flags.passw}`,email: e, quota: q,apikey: a,privileges: p }, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
                    fs.writeFileSync("temptoken.txt",token);
                } else {
                    console.log("Wrong username or password\n");
                }       
         });
```

After the login the user can perform various queries, where in their code they perform an

`axios.get` where I pass the header like this:

```
    const axios = require('axios');
        const {flags} = this.parse(ActualTotalLoadCommand); 
        var fs=require('fs');
        var token = fs.readFileSync('temptoken.txt');
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']=token;
```

From my server side file where I have the file entry.routes.js **how can I capture the token and then decode it to test for example if the user who performed the query is a valid user**?

The entry.routes.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = app => {
  const entry = require("../controlers/entry.controller.js");

  // Retrieve a single Entry with Id
  var fs=require('fs');
  var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/home/vangelis/softeng/energy/private.key');
  var jwt=require('express-jwt');
  app.use(
    jwt({
      secret: privateKey,
      credentialsRequired: false,
      getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
        if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
            return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
          return req.query.token;
        }
        return null;
      }
    }));
  app.get("/entry/:Id", entry.findOne);

  app.get("/energy/api/ActualTotalLoad/:AreaName/:Resolution/date/:Year-:Month-:Day", entry.findTwo);
```

As you can see **I tried using express-jwt**, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above you create the header with:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']=token;
```

which will result in

`Authorization: <the token>`

but in the code to read the header :

```
if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer')
```

you expect a header like this:

`Authorization: Bearer <the token>`

which is the standard way. So you should add `Bearer` to the line to create the header.

Beside that, I see you're putting the (encrypted) password into the token. That's something you should avoid. There'sno good reason to do it. You have authenticated the user before you created the token and now, when you receive the token, you verify the authenticity of that token by it's signature.